# Directus CMS - User Invitation not working

Tags: php, content-management-system, directus

Reset password function works, at the main login screen, works correctly and sends emails out to users requesting it.

However, when logged in as Admin, it won't let me invite users to it's users collection. No email is ever being sent out to those users. Generally creating a user and deleting it and then creating it again also does not work. Once deleted a user with that email cannot be readded again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug. I would recommend opening a ticket on the GitHub repo:

https://github.com/directus/app/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=